# Print Hellow World without modifying Main method java

Tags: java

here is code

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

And my question is that how to print `Hello World` without touching main method?

I tried using static block but then Output comes like

```
World
Hello
```

But i want `Hello World` in same line.

Comment: Use `static{System.out.println("Hello World");}` block..

Comment: Show your complete code. Ask your  question clearly..

Comment: yes if i use static{System.out.println("Hello World");} block then output comes like

Hello World
Hello

but i want Hello World

Comment: this question is asked in a test..

Comment: You are telling wrong.. How it will come like

Comment: i m telling the exact which is asked in test.

Comment: are you sure it doesn't say System.out.print("Hello"); ?

Comment: yes in test they said that print Hello World together, without touching main method

Comment: yes i also wrote in answer that answer will come like

Hello World
Hello

but they said my answer is wrong..
i also wrote static block there

Comment: Use `System.exit(0);` at the end of your static block and `main` will not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Test {

    static {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        System.out.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: wow perfect.. your answer worked.. that is what i want..
and i m going to mark your answer as helpful ..

Comment: thank u so much buddy ..:)

Comment: you can also use System.exit(-1) instead of  System.out.close();